# Fetching records from database using fetch but getting error 400

Tags: reactjs, spring, fetch

```
export class ProductVariation extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            productdata: {}
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const {
            id
        } = this.props.history.location.state?.productId;
        console.log(id);
        fetch(
                `http://localhost:8080/productVariationDisplay/${id}`, {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
                    }
                }
            )
            .then(response => response.data)
            .then(data => this.setState({
                productdata: data
            }))

    }

    render() {
        return ( <
            p > this.state.data.price < /p>
        );
    }
}
```

export default ProductVariation;

**I am trying to fetch records from database but I am getting 400 error when I tried to print the value of id variable I get undefined athough this api works fine on postman I tried to manually also give idea in api then I get status as 200 but no records are still not fetched from database can anyone tell me why?**

Comment: Can you hardcode ${id} in URL: `http://localhost:8080/productVariationDisplay/${id}` for some id and then try?

Comment: Yes I tried I have mentioned in the comment but still I am not able to fetch my records

Comment: You mean `console.log(id);` is undefined?